# d3.js Map not rendering on Internet Explorer or Firefox, Only Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, geojson

The path elements d attribute is where the problem is at. When looking at the console in Internet Explorer it explicitly mentions

> SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be
>   completely parsed.

It doesn't seem to be the geojson I'm using as it works in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t9sd08q7/1/

Here are the outputs when inspecting into the dom elements on each browser.

Chrome : 
[image: chrome_paths]

Internet Explorer :

[image: internetexplorer_paths]

Firefox : 
[image]

This is how I'm generating my path:

```
 function initialSetup() {
     internalScope.svg.selectAll("path").transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0).remove();

     internalScope.width = width = internalScope.svg[0][0].offsetWidth;
     internalScope.height = height = 800;
     projection = d3.geo.albers()
                        .rotate(4.4, 0)
                        .parallels([50, 60])
                        .scale(1)
                        .translate([0, 0]);
     path = d3.geo.path()
                  .projection(projection); // default path based on our projection

     internalScope.svg.attr("height", "100%")
                      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
                      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet"); // prevent default height messing up svg

     // Append an outer rectangle so when it's clicked it will also reset back to all features view
     internalScope.svg.append("rect")
         .attr("class", "background")
         .attr("width", "100%")
         .attr("height", "100%")
         .on("click", function () {
             //TODO clicking the empty space could potentially do some sort of reset on everything ?
         })
     ;

     var groupofSvgElements = internalScope.svg.append("g");

     return groupofSvgElements;
 }
```

I pass the "groupOfSvgElements" to another method wh

Extracted code that I'm using to generate the d3.js map (inside an Angularjs directive).

```
function renderCountries(matchCounts) {

     var promise = processJson(internalScope.json.uk_countries).then(function (json) {
         if (matchCounts) {
             json.features = matchFeaturesToLocationsWithCounts(json.features);
         }

         var projectionProperties = generateScaleTranslate(json, path, width, height);

         projection
             .scale(projectionProperties.scale)
             .translate(projectionProperties.translate);

         internalScope.groupofSvgElements.selectAll()
             .data(json.features)
             .enter()
             .append("path")
             .attr("id", function (d) {
                 if (d.properties.Name === 'Ireland') {
                     return "Ireland";
                 } else {
                     return "country";
                 }
             })
             .attr("class", function (d) {
                 if (isNaN(d.properties.Total) || d.properties.Total == 0) { // this covers instances where the capita average is NaN because of the maths or if the total job counts are just 0
                     return "map-feature map-shade-0";
                 } else {
                     return "map-feature " + internalScope.quantizeMethod(d.properties.Total);
                 }
             })
             .attr("d", path)
             .on("click", function (d) {
                 sendStats(d.properties);
                 updateLineChart(d);
                 internalScope.$apply();
                 console.log("hello, you clicked a Country with the count " + d.properties.Total);
             });
     }, function (error) {
         $log.error("Error when procession json file - Error : " + error);
     });

     return promise;
 }
```

My json file - don't really know how to add it to a fiddle or share it here.
http://jsonblob.com/5595338ce4b051e806c87b42

Comment: The path calculation is going bad on IE and FF. Can you share your code, especially the code that populates the 'd' attribute?

Comment: To the person who has -1'd my post could you at least have the courtesy to explain why? Have I not put in enough effort asking my question? I don't see a problem with the question, it seems fairly clear and concise, could you show me what is wrong?

Comment: The code doesn't help because it doesn't show how the ```path``` variable is calculated. We need to understand why the 'd' attribute is populated differently in different browsers. Best would be to create a JSFiddle. (I suspect the lack of a working example is the reason for the -1 vote.)

Comment: Good news, it's not the geojson file (yayy) - http://jsfiddle.net/t9sd08q7/1/ ... bad news, I still don't have a clue what it is and was kinda hoping it was some sort of formatting on the geojson file. Tested in Internet explorer, it works..

Comment: @EthanJewett I misread your comment. I didn't realise it was important how the path was being calculated, hang on let me get that from my code and try add that to the fiddle too.

Comment: Hopefully my latest edit gives enough context of what I'm doing.

Comment: The JSFiddle is going in the right direction. But it works fine in Firefox, so I suspect it is something in your code that is not in the fiddle causing the problem. What happens in the matchFeaturesToLocationsWithCounts and generateScaleTranslate functions? I'd recommend working to recreate your problem in jsFiddle. I suspect this process will help you find the answer yourself, but if not, it will make it much faster for others to look at the issue.

Comment: Okay, I'll start adding the other bits into the fiddle, I was hoping this was a smaller issue and didn't realise it would take this much time to fix. I'll have a full day tomorrow to get back and start adding stuff, thanks for your help thus far :)

Comment: Started adding everything and found the culprit. It was the way I was generating wid. I was doing some funky svg[0][0].offsetWidth, changing that to var parent = element.$$element.parent(); width = parent[0].clientWidth fixes that issue. Again thank you for your help. Time to fix the next half dozen issues with multi-browser compatability :) Also, do I delete this question ? or do I leave it out there? I never know what to do in the scenarios where I've put up a question, ended up debugging my way into it later realising the answer isn't really going to help other people.

Comment: Cool. Glad it worked. I'd say leave it up. Recreation is the key to debugging these types of issues, so in a sense this is exactly the answer other people with this type of problem will need :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed.

There can be many reasons the following bug occurs, in my case it was how the width was being passed to the path construction. It seems that Chrome is very lenient on a lot more than Internet Explorer.

The best way to debug this problem (as suggested by Ethan Jewett in the above comments) was to use the same geojson in a jsfiddle which I uploaded to myjson.com. Snippet of the code that uses it

```
d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/4wkia", function (error, json) {
```

I think this problem only occurs because SVG isn't really regulated across browsers as well as it should be. There's not really much error information either as to what is causing the problem. There was no error that the width was invalid for the path generation. Only way to debug this was to add bits of my own code to the jsfiddle little by little. Final Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t9sd08q7/11/

Comment: offsetWidth and clientWidth are from CSSOM and it's true that they are not terribly cross-browser but they aren't SVG.